# Discord bot sends response twice

Tags: node.js, npm, discord, discord.js, gcloud

I'm coding a discord.js bot, and whenever I send a command, it gives a response twice. I've concluded it's because I have too many instances running. I try to delete the instances, but it doesn't delete. Sometimes it says "Some instances could not be deleted", and sometimes it doesn't delete at all.

And through Terminal

```
SERVICE  VERSION          ID                                VM_STATUS  DEBUG_MODE
default  20191208t223728  aef-default-20191208t223728-0l57  RUNNING
default  20191208t223728  aef-default-20191208t223728-jb53  RUNNING
default  20191208t223728  aef-default-20191208t223728-wpgm  RUNNING
```

[This is what the messages look like. There should only be one message, not three.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PBcS.png)

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Custom bot for Chinese Discord server.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jacob Villorente",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2",
    "discord.js-commando": "^0.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "ytdl-core": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to resolve your problem. 
The first one, and the better, is to use **grep** to get all your node processes who are running on your machine:

```
ps -ef | grep node
```

Then, you will be able to kill them with `kill` command.

The second way is to change your discord bot token. All the instances will be errored so you're sure there's no instance launched anymore.

Comment: Would I run it through my Mac's terminal or SSH?

Comment: On the device on which the instances are launched. If it's a VPS, probably via SSH. If you launched the instances locally, probably using you're Max's terminal.

Comment: I tried both methods, which did not work. The first one did nothing. The second one errored it as you said, then came back.

Comment: OK, there is a third way. Reboot your computer... It will exit all node processes.