# Unhandled promise warn. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, promise, discord, discord.js

I have bot which get user message content, delete user message, then send private message to message.author and then send content of user message in embed.
After few messages bot sends 2 messages instead of 1 and warn appears. Any idea how to fix it?

**Warn:**

> superadmin@vps-XXXXXX:~/path$ node test.js (node:1059)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
> at RequestHandler.execute (path/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) (node:1059)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:1059) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

**Script:**

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;

client.on('message', message => {
if (message.author === client.user && message.channel.id !== (508728211837026325)) {
  return;
}
if (message.channel.id == (508728211837026325)) {
  message.delete();
  message.author.send("Success!");
  message.channel.send({
    "embed": {
      "color": 61183,
      "description": message.content + "\n\nCreated by: " + "<@" + message.author.id + ">",
      "author": {
        "icon_url": "imgururl;",
        "url": "imgururl",
        "name": "test",
      },
      timestamp: new Date()
    }
  })
}
})
client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe is probably caused by the fact that your bot is launched twice at the same time. Indeed, if your bot is launched twice:

- you're getting the Unknown Message warning, as the message was already deleted by another instance of the bot.
- the bot sends the message twice.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255618/11856499), it should fix your issue.

Comment: I know now now. I forget to turn off screen (XD)

Comment: Hi @rokky30 , if this is the right answer, would you mind pressing the “mark as correct” button, so other users know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The bot is being activated by himself.

```js
if (message.author === client.user && message.channel.id !== (508728211837026325))

# should probably be
if (message.author === client.user || message.channel.id !== (508728211837026325))
```

On another note, the channel id is a twitter snowflake, which can be as big as a uint64, for javascript, that means you can't handle an id that is too large because the limit is 9007199254740991, so you should use the string versions.

```js
if (message.channel.id === "508728211837026325")
```